# How can I remove my bathroom sink stopper?

Tags: bathroom, repair, drain, sink

I bought a house where the drain plug doesn't work properly in my bathroom. I want to replace it with a plug that can be removed so that I can put a SinkShroom (just like TubShroom, but smaller) to catch hair. All I can find are ones where the plug can't be fully removed. What specific kind of mechanism/assembly should I be looking for?

Comment: how about a picture ??

Comment: I removed the request for brands, etc. as that makes this a shopping question and that's explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Please take the [tour] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Most sink stoppers are controlled by a shaft that intersects the drain pipe just below the sink. A plastic ball serves as a swivel which seals against the pipe. You can remove that by unscrewing its nut or unclipping its retainer, as appropriate.

Once that's done, pull the shaft out, pull out the stopper, and *replace the shaft and ball*. You need those in there to seal the drain. They should be low enough to not interfere with your hair catcher.

FYI, the most common reasons such stoppers quit working is because they were forced and get detached from the shaft, either by slipping off or breaking. With that knowledge you can *repair* your stopper if you choose, or reinstall it later.